Use sequelize with includes, schema and scope
I have to write complex sql queries with TypeScript, using sequelize, defining scope and schema.
The problem is that if you write a query using includes (joins) and schema configuration, the schema will only work at the first level and subsequent tables will remain without schema.
Example:
Models:
@Scopes(() => ({
  ['simpleScope']: simpleScope,
  ['completeScope']: completeScope,
  pagination: paginationModelScope,
}))
@Table({
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
  paranoid: true,
  tableName: 'user',
})
export class User extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column
  id: number;

  // [...] Other fields

  @ForeignKey(() => Profile)
  @Column({ allowNull: false, type: DataType.INTEGER })
 profile_id: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => Profile)
  declare readonly profile: Profile;
}

@Scopes(() => ({
  ['simpleScope']: simpleScope,
  ['completeScope']: completeScope,
  pagination: paginationModelScope,
}))
@Table({
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
  paranoid: true,
  tableName: 'profile',
})
export class Profile extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  id: number;

  // [...] Other fields

  @BelongsToMany(() => Permission, () => ProfilePermission)
  permission?: Permission[];
}

@Scopes(() => ({
  simpleScope: simpleScope,
  pagination: paginationModelScope,
}))
@Table({
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
  paranoid: true,
  tableName: 'permission',
})
export class Permission extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
  id: number;

  // [...] Other fields

  @ApiProperty({ type: () => Profile, nullable: true, isArray: true })
  @BelongsToMany(() => Profile, () => ProfilePermission)
  profile?: Profile[];
}

Scope:
import { IncludeOptions } from 'sequelize';

export function completeScope(): IncludeOptions {
  return {
    attributes: {
      exclude: ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'senha'],
      include: [],
    },
    include: [
      {
        association: 'profile',
        required: true,
        paranoid: true,
        attributes: {
          exclude: ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'],
          include: [],
        },
        include: [
          {
            association: 'permission',
            required: true,
            paranoid: false,
            attributes: {
              exclude: ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'],
              include: [],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
}

Query:
public static async findOne<Response = any>(model, id, scope: any = 'completeScope', schema: string): Promise<Response> {
  const response = await model.schema(schema).scope([scope]).findOne({ where: { id } });

  if (response === null) {
    throw new NotFoundException('Not found!');
  }

  return response;
}

Usage:
async findOne(id, scope, schema) {
  return BasicCrud.findOne(this.UserModel, id, scope, schema);
}

EXECUTED QUERY:
Executed (default): SELECT "User"."id", "User"."email", "User"."profile_id", "profile"."id" AS "profile.id", "profile"."name" AS "profile.name", "profile->permission"."id" AS "profile.permission.id", "profile->permission"."name" AS "profile.permission.name", "profile->permission->ProfilePermission"."profile_id" AS "profile.permission.ProfilePermission.profile_id", "profile->permission->ProfilePermission"."permission_id" AS "profile.permission.ProfilePermission.permission_id",
 "profile->permission->ProfilePermission"."created_at" AS "profile.permission.ProfilePermission.created_at", "profile->permission->ProfilePermission"."updated_at" AS "profile.permission.ProfilePermission.updated_at" FROM "SCHEMA"."User" AS "User" INNER JOIN "profile" AS "profile" ON "User"."profile_id" = "profile"."id" AND ("profile"."deleted_at" IS NULL) INNER JOIN ( "profile_permission" AS "profile->permission->ProfilePermission" INNER JOIN "permission" AS "profile->permission" ON "profile->permission"."id" = "profile->permission->ProfilePermission"."permission_id") ON "profile"."id" = "profile->permission->ProfilePermission"."profile_id" WHERE ("User"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "User"."id" = 1);

As in this example above, SCHEMA is defined before USER and PROFILE/PERMISSION remain without schema.
Is there a way to pass the schema for all the models related with the query?
Obs: I receive the schema within each service and define it dynamically when I call the database query.

Please add model definitions to the post. Usually schema is indicated in the Sequelize instance options or in each model definition

I can see you are used to use cmds as "foreign key". Try to use Sequelize hasMany and similar. Too many things can be defined with just hasMany. I have been playing with hasMany and several natural foreign keys appear in the definition of tables.

I don't see any signs of schema defined in any models. How do you indicate it? To work with the same models in different schemas simultaneously you need to register them as many times as many schemas you have.

It wasn't clear to me what you meant. The schema is being defined at the time of the call where I use Model.schema('mySchema'); passing the name of my schema.
Or do you mean that for each different schema I need to have a different model? Can you please give me an example of what you mean by "you need to register them as many times as you have schemas."?
NOTE: all tables/models exist in all schemas, they are replicas that contain different records but the same structure.
